# Не могу войти на сайт через Firefox

Tags: дефект, аутентификация

Почему-то я никак не могу войти на сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/. Все время выбрасывает на регистрацию. Хотя я уже давно зарегистрирован, задавал вопросы и отвечал на вопросы других участников.

Прилагаю последовательность экранов, которые вижу. Причем это относится только к браузеру Firefox. В Safari  захожу нормально.

Как это исправить?

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

[image: Screen3]

[image: Screen4]

---

и вот сейчас захожу в FireFox, а картинка все та же.

[image: скриншот входа]

Comment: Попробуйте кэш браузера почистить.

Comment: Не вполне понимаю куда именно вы пытаетесь войти... Главная страница для анонимного пользователя выглядит по-другому, не как на скриншоте.

Comment: @PavelMayorov человек мог участвовать на других сайтах (на английском SO к примеру), не заходя на SO на русском. Поэтому тут ещё шаг "присоединиться к сообществу" может быть (+100 бонус)¶ Я проверил: могу как зайти так и присоединиться на firefox 61 на Ubuntu.

Comment: А в приватном окне пробовал?

Comment: @jfs, но у него-то мак?

Comment: Если OS имеет значение, то следует её явно упомянуть (я не вижу в вопросе. Safari не только в macOS может быть), и даже в заголовок и/или метки OS явно упомянуть можно.

Comment: @maxMas скажите, а какую кнопку вы нажимаете? Вы пробовали нажать "Присоединиться к сообществу"?

Comment: @maxMas а выйти с сайта и войти обратно вы не пробовали?

Comment: я указывал в посте адрес, по которому вхожу. Вот он - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/. Потом, в Safari все нормально, проблема с FireFox. И далее, действия типа почистить кэш, перезагрузить, выйти и заново зайти, предпринимались неоднократно. Но проблема и ныне там.

Comment: и да, кнопку Присоединиться к сообществу тоже нажимал и неоднократно. Открывается окно, такое как на скриншоте, где Гугл и Фейсбук. И все идет по тому же кругу.